# R select the two max values in dataframe grouped by factor

Tags: r, filter

I have the following dataframe

```
v=c(1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(V1 = randomNumbers(n = 18,min = 0,max = 1, col=1),
                 factor_col = c(rep("A", 18)),
                 sessions = rep(v, each=6))

v=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = randomNumbers(n = 24,min = 0,max = 1, col=1),
                  factor_col = c(rep("B", 24)),
                  sessions = rep(v, each=3))

v=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12)
df3 <- data.frame(V1 = randomNumbers(n = 33,min = 0,max = 1, col=1),
                  factor_col = c(rep("C", 33)),
                  sessions = rep(v, each=3))

Table = bind_rows(df, df2)
Table = bind_rows(Table, df3)
```

how do I filter for the two max values of `sessions` per each factor of `factor_col` and calculate the average of `V1` across those lase two sessions, for each `factor_col`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
Table %>% distinct(factor_col, sessions)  %>% group_by(factor_col) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 2, order_by = sessions) %>% left_join(Table) %>%
  group_by(sessions, factor_col) %>% summarise(v1_mean = mean(V1))


# sessions factor_col v1_mean
# <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>
# 1        2 A            0.5  
# 2        3 A            0.333
# 3        7 B            0.667
# 4        8 B            0    
# 5       11 C            0.667
# 6       12 C            0.667
```

Comment: apologies @Juan C I changed my question because I realised that I actually had a different problem, and your answer is no longer valid for the problem that I have, see above, thanks!

Comment: Changed my answer to better fit your example

Comment: thank you! so for example now I have more levels of  factor_col and despite increasing the slice_max n value it is still not selecting the last 2 sessions, so how does slice_max actually work? and how can I adjust it for varying levels of factor_col? thanks!

Comment: The distinct keeps only one row per combination of sessions and factor_col. Then, for each factor col, we get the two highest sessions with slice_max, increasing n should get you more sessions per factor_col